# How to fork a database everyday automatically in Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to newly fork a PostgreSQL database and delete an old one every day automatically in Heroku.

Is it possible? Is there any webhook or script or whatever that I can manage?

Comment: This seems a little extreme. What is the actual issue you need to solve? BTW you can accomplish what you asked for by adding the following as first statement in your creation script and re-running it: **drop database *db_name* if exists;**. Then use a cron job, or what ever scheduler you have, to execute the create script.